# index of out of range error while parsing json array

Tags: android

Im using the follwoing code to parse json array which is within json object.

```
JSONObject notificationResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONObject value = new JSONObject(notificationResponse.getString("value"));
JSONArray details = value.optJSONArray("details");
final int numberOfItems = details.length();

for (int i =0; i <= numberOfItems; i++ ){
JSONObject jsonObjects = details.getJSONObject(i);
String text = jsonObjects.getString("text");
String date = jsonObjects.getString("date & time");
Log.d(TAG,text + " " +date);
  }

 } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Following is my json.

```
{"status":1,"value":{"details":[{"text":"sample", "date & time":"12-NOV-15 3:30pm"}]}}
```

My code `out of range` exception at `JSONObject jsonObjects = details.getJSONObject(i);`

Comment: just replace forloop <= condition with < only

Comment: remove equal sign
i<numberIOfitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using following:

```
for (int i =0; i < numberOfItems; i++ ){
JSONObject jsonObjects = details.getJSONObject(i);
String text = jsonObjects.getString("text");
String date = jsonObjects.getString("date & time");
Log.d(TAG,text + " " +date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for (int i =0; i < numberOfItems; i++ )
{
JSONObject jsonObjects = details.getJSONObject(i);
String text = jsonObjects.getString("text");
String date = jsonObjects.getString("date & time");
 Log.d(TAG,text + " " +date);
 }
```

instead of

```
   for (int i =0; i <= numberOfItems; i++ )
   {
   JSONObject jsonObjects = details.getJSONObject(i);
   String text = jsonObjects.getString("text");
   String date = jsonObjects.getString("date & time");
   Log.d(TAG,text + " " +date);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
     use `i < numberOfItems;`  instead of `i <= numberOfItems;`

```
JSONObject notificationResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONObject value = new JSONObject(notificationResponse.getString("value"));
JSONArray details = value.optJSONArray("details");
final int numberOfItems = details.length();

for (int i =0; i < numberOfItems; i++ ){
JSONObject jsonObjects = details.getJSONObject(i);
String text = jsonObjects.getString("text");
String date = jsonObjects.getString("date & time");
Log.d(TAG,text + " " +date);
  }

 } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

remove = from your for loop

```
for (int i =0; i < numberOfItems; i++ )
```

`JsonArray` index will start from 0, so `length()` will return (total size-1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initiating the loop as **i=0** thus condition should be modified as below:

```
for (int i =0; i < numberOfItems; i++ ){
}
```

instead of

```
for (int i =0; i <= numberOfItems; i++ ){
}
```